# How to get camera on which known photo was taken

Tags: flickr, flickrj

my question concerns the API of flickr.com. Type of camera is visible below each photo directly on the site, but I do not see any method in the API which allow to obtain it from my application. Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: It's likely the camera type is being retrieved from the EXIF data inside the image file.  There's plenty of sample code online on how to read EXIF data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [flickr.photos.getExif](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getExif.html) endpoint, and then examine the `tag="Make"` and `tag="Model"` data that you get back.  An example snippet of returned data:

```
<exif tagspace="IFD0" tagspaceid="0" tag="Make" label="Make">
  <raw>NIKON</raw>
</exif>
<exif tagspace="IFD0" tagspaceid="0" tag="Model" label="Model">
  <raw>COOLPIX L620</raw>
</exif>
```